# how to split table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get a data set about 70 thousand rows and now I want to split this table into three with exact number of rows(the code was fisrt applied in SAS and now move to postgresql),one from 1-5000,two from 5001-25000 and last one with the rest row,and no duplicated rows in any of them.
like:

```
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
| cst_id | age | salary | sex |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|      1 |  44 |   2000 | M   |
|      2 |  23 |   3000 | F   |
|      3 |  34 |   4000 | M   |
|      4 |  51 |   5000 | M   |
|      5 |  26 |   6000 | F   |
|      6 |  28 |   7000 | F   |
|      7 |  39 |   8000 | M   |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
```

finally I want three table with the exact number of rows I assign(such as 3rows-2rows-rest rows),and they are all distinct.like:
table1:

```
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
| cst_id | age | salary | sex |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|      1 |  44 |   2000 | M   |
|      2 |  23 |   3000 | F   |
|      3 |  34 |   4000 | M   |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
```

table2:

```
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
| cst_id | age | salary | sex |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|      4 |  51 |   5000 | M   |
|      5 |  26 |   6000 | F   |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
```

table3:

```
 +--------+-----+--------+-----+
| cst_id | age | salary | sex |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|      6 |  28 |   7000 | F   |
|      7 |  39 |   8000 | M   |
+--------+-----+--------+-----+
```

how to use postgresql to finish this?

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @YahyaHussein how to use postgresql to finish the split job described above？

Comment: I assume you just want to select a set with distinct rows and row_number and then insert it in chunks?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I have edited it ,please check

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited it,please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split this process into steps as a function.

1. Get the total number of distinct rows.
2. Divide that value by 3 and store the value as a DECLARED variable (_size).
3. Create table_1, table_2, and table_3.
4. INSERT INTO table_1 with LIMIT (_size).
5. INSERT INTO table_2 with LIMIT (_size) WHERE id > table_1's greatest id.
6. INSERT INTO table_3 with LIMIT (_size) WHERE id > table_2's greatest id.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a window function "NTILE" can do this:

-- add a col to help split
create temp table help_table as
select *
  ,NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY cat_id) as batch_nbr
from your_table;

create table_1 as
select * from help_table where batch_nbr = 1;

create table_2 as
select * from help_table where batch_nbr = 2;

create table_3 as
select * from help_table where batch_nbr = 3;

Comment: I loved this NTILE function